# How to selectively enable onEachFeature function with geojson

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a working geojson polygon map with [leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/). I use `onEachFeature onclick` to hyperlink when user clicks on a polygon.

How to I disable *click event* for polygons where `attribute = 0` and enable where `attribute = 1`?

Here is an example of my work [Map](http://tinyurl.com/gs5krsp)

```
function onclick(e) {
     window.open(e.target.feature.properties.link);
}


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: onclick
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got access to the actual feature in the `onEachFeature` method so you could do a conditional like this:

```
function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight
    });
    if (feature.properties.somevalue === 1) {
        layer.on('click', onclick);
    }
}
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vyXqW86Tv7tuLy0GwcPR?p=preview